# шифрование swap и home на уже установленой системе Linux

Tags: linux, администрирование, шифрование, kali-linux

НА машине установлена Kali linux последней версии. установка производилась баз шифрования диска. Теперь хочу зашифровать разделы swap и  home, при этом системный раздел оставить открытым для сохранения производительности. Как это сделать какими средствами и что бы без кучи убитого времени. Отдельная благодарность за развёрнутый ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Со свопом всё просто. Сначала `swapoff -a`, потом через dm-crypt

```
/etc/crypttab
# <name>  <device>                                                         <password>     <options>
swap      /dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD2500BEVT-22ZCT0_WD-WXE908VF0470-part3  /dev/urandom   swap,cipher=aes-cbc-essiv:sha256,size=256
```

В fstab меняешь раздел подкачки на /dev/mapper/swap

Или пересоздаешь как LUKS. Тут несколько способов https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Swap_encryption

Comment: а что скажешь насчёт home раздела, как его зашифровать тем же ключём не пересоздавая

Comment: Веракрипт умеет дошифровывать разделы, позже опишу..

Comment: буду очень признателен. не понимаю почему до сих пор процесс шифрования не доведён до убобного и функционального автоматизма

Comment: емпро eы наверно забыл ri про меня

Comment: да всё дела, посмотрите другие статьи